# HTTP basic authentication URL with special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rubygems

I'm using a hosted Artifactory RubyGems remote repo to pull dependencies. The Artifactory remote repo uses Basic auth so I need to provide username and password in the format of `gem source -a 'https://${user}:${passwd}@my_artifactory.com/artifactory/api/gems/mygems`

Problem is that my username is an email address and my password contains special chars ('#', '&', and '^') too. I've tried to percent-encode on various url parts but none worked

${user} has format of `abc@example.com` and ${passwd} has format of `1a^2b#3c&4d`

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing it via the web browser? Chrome is stripping the auth details out

> The use of these URLs is deprecated. In Chrome, the username:password@ part in URLs is even stripped out for security reasons. In Firefox, it is checked if the site actually requires authentication and if not, Firefox will warn the user with a prompt "You are about to log in to the site “www.example.com” with the username “username”, but the website does not require authentication. This may be an attempt to trick you."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

If it's not Chrome stripping it out, perhaps you missed out a char by mistake? Try using this website to encode them and see if that works.

https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: no I'm not using web browser but rather in CLI. I tried the following but none worked:
- encode the whole string

- encode only `@` in either username or hostname

- encode special characters in my password

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should encode username + password but not the `:` in between